# ASM: find descriptor of a generic type

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am creating a utility based on ASM to generate class on the fly. One of the thing I need is to generate a method signature that has generic type as parameter. E.g.

```
public void setValue(List<String> value) {...}
```

The question is how can I get the descriptor of `List<String>` using ASM library. I know there is a utility method `asm.Type.getDescriptor(Class)`, I wonder is there anything like `getDescriptor(java.lang.reflect.Type)`, or how can I implement that?

Thank... Green

Comment: For your descriptor you would just use list. The signature is what you would modify in order to implement generics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a signature, not a descriptor. A descriptor is always refering to raw types.

With ASM, you would typically use [a `SignatureVisitor`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureVisitor.html) for this purpose. For your example, you can create the signature for `void : List<String>` by:

```
SignatureVisitor sv = new SignatureWriter();
SignatureVisitor psv = sv.visitParameterType();
psv.visitClassType(Type.getInternalName(List.class));
SignatureVisitor ppsv = psv.visitTypeArgument('=');
ppsv.visitClassType(Type.getInternalName(String.class));
psv.visitEnd();
SignatureVisitor rtv = sv.visitReturnType();
rtv.visitBaseType('V');
String signature = sv.toString();
```

The signature visitor API is as intuitive as the other visitor APIs due to the conditional requirement of calling `visitEnd` but reading the javadoc allows learning the implications.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just for someone who need this, here is my [implementation](https://github.com/actframework/actframework/blob/master/src/main/java/act/inject/param/JsonDTOClassGenerator.java#L84):

```
private static String typeDesc(BeanSpec spec) {
    String root = classDesc(spec.rawType());
    List<java.lang.reflect.Type> typeParams = spec.typeParams();
    if (typeParams.isEmpty()) {
        return root;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = S.builder("<");
    for (java.lang.reflect.Type type : typeParams) {
        BeanSpec specx = BeanSpec.of(type, null, spec.injector());
        sb.append(typeDesc(specx));
    }
    sb.append(">");
    FastStr str = FastStr.of(root);
    str = str.take(str.length() - 1).append(sb.toString()).append(";");
    return str.toString();
}

private static String classDesc(Class c) {
    if (c.isPrimitive()) {
        c = $.wrapperClassOf(c);
    }
    return Type.getDescriptor(c);
}
```